# Can you set a variable for LIMIT OFFSET in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, limit, offset

So I was doing a project that required us to create a program in python and I was wondering if you could use a variable for the OFFSET value so that it can be increased through "if" functions.

Here is the code I came up with.

```
> c.execute("SELECT * FROM Book_reservation WHERE Status='Pending' LIMIT 20 OFFSET ?",(Num))
```

But when I tried it, all I got was a "parameters are of unsupported type" error message. Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

An int in parentheses is just an int. See what `type( (5)  )` returns. The argument to `execute` requires a sequence. It will be seen as a tuple if written `(Num,)`. Or the argument can be a list, eg `[Num]`.

Answer (score 0):

AS @DinoCoderSaurus mentioned, the argument to execute requires a sequence.Just add a comma(,) after the variable.
Assuming you have the variable Num = 5
This should work:

```
> c.execute("SELECT * FROM Book_reservation WHERE Status='Pending' LIMIT 20 OFFSET ?",(Num,))
```